# Convert PropertyInfo into Func<> delegate

Tags: c#

I have many data model objects that have primary key fields decorated with DataAnnotations.KeyAttributes:

```
public class Example
{
  [Key]
  [Column("FirstKey", Order = 1)]
  public Guid FirstKey { get; set; }

  [Key]
  [Column("SecondKey", Order = 2)]
  public Guid SecondKey { get; set; }

  [Column("Unimportant", Order = 3)]
  public int UnimportantField {get; set; }
}
```

I can select out the Key fields of the data model objects using PropertInfo:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetKeyProperties<T>(this T source)
{
  PropertyInfo[] properties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
  return properties.Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(KeyAttribute)));
}
```

I can also manually construct an anonymous object that contains the Key fields for a given class:

```
public static object GetKeyObjectForExample(Example example)
{
  return new { example.FirstKey, example.SecondKey };
}
```

I would like to create a generic method that will construct a Func delegate that will return an anonymous object containing the Key fields.

```
public static Func<T, object> GetKeyFunction<T>(this T source)
{
  //construct Func<T, object> using IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>?
}
```

So invoking the GetKeyFunction method for a given instance of Example would return a Func delegate.  This delegate should produce equivalent output to the GetKeyObjectForExample method.

How can I implement that GetKeyFunction method?

Comment: I don't think you can dynamically create an anonymous type. However, you could return an `dynamic` instead.

Comment: You cant pass annonymous objects as return types or parameters. You could return a tuple

Comment: Yuval - thanks for the feedback.  Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).  I'm passing them as objects in my current production code, so it's working fine.

Comment: You lose the point when casting them to object, how do you access back their properties then?

Comment: Yuval - I don't access their properties.  Instead, I use them to check equivalency to other identity objects.  So I might search a list of objects by passing in a key object and asking each of them if their key object is equal to the passed in one.

Comment: Alright, whatever works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve as even with a dynamic or anonymous object you will need to know the names of the Key fields anyway, but something like this would do the trick for your stated approach (error handling and such elided):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class KeyAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
    public class Example
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid FirstKey { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public Guid SecondKey { get; set; }

        public int UnimportantField { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example e = new Example()
            {
                FirstKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
                SecondKey = Guid.NewGuid()
            };

            var func = GetKeyFunction<Example>();

            var key = func(e);
            Console.WriteLine(key.FirstKey);
            Console.WriteLine(key.SecondKey);
        }

        public static Func<T, dynamic> GetKeyFunction<T>()
        {
            return (t) =>
                {
                    var dyn = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
                    foreach (var p in GetKeyProperties(typeof(T)))
                    {
                        dyn.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(t));
                    }
                    return dyn;
                };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetKeyProperties(Type t)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
            return properties.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<KeyAttribute>().Any());
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After reading some of the comments you could get fancy with this approach and add an Equals and GetHashCode implementation to your dynamic object (this implementation assumes that the name of the key field is important in equality). Feels like too much code and dynamics for deteremining object equality but...

Same code as above but with a helper class to determine dictionary equality and hashcodes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class KeyAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
    public class Example
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid FirstKey { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public Guid SecondKey { get; set; }

        public int UnimportantField { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example e = new Example()
            {
                FirstKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
                SecondKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UnimportantField = 0
            };

            var func = GetKeyFunction<Example>();

            var key = func(e);
            Console.WriteLine(key.FirstKey);
            Console.WriteLine(key.SecondKey);

            Console.WriteLine(key.Equals(key));
            Console.WriteLine(key.GetHashCode());

            Example e2 = new Example()
            {
                FirstKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
                SecondKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UnimportantField = 1
            };

            var key2 = func(e2);
            Console.WriteLine(key2.FirstKey);
            Console.WriteLine(key2.SecondKey);
            Console.WriteLine(key.Equals(key2));
            Console.WriteLine(key2.GetHashCode());
        }

        public static Func<T, dynamic> GetKeyFunction<T>()
        {
            return (t) =>
                {
                    var dyn = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
                    foreach (var p in GetKeyProperties(typeof(T)))
                    {
                        dyn.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(t));
                    }
                    dyn.Add("Equals", (Func<object, bool>)((o) => 
                        {
                            var comparer = new DictionaryComparer<string,object>();
                            return comparer.Equals(dyn as IDictionary<string,object>, o as IDictionary<string,object>);
                        }
                        ));

                    dyn.Add("GetHashCode", (Func<int>)(() =>
                        {
                            var comparer = new DictionaryComparer<string, object>();
                            return comparer.GetHashCode(dyn as IDictionary<string, object>);
                        }
                        ));
                    return dyn;
                };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetKeyProperties(Type t)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
            return properties.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<KeyAttribute>().Any());
        }
    }

    public class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : EqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
    {
        public DictionaryComparer()
        {
        }
        public override bool Equals(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> x, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
        {
            // early-exit checks
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;

            if (null == x || y == null)
                return false;

            if (x.Count != y.Count)
                return false;

            // check keys are the same
            foreach (TKey k in x.Keys)
                if (!y.ContainsKey(k))
                    return false;

            // check values are the same
            foreach (TKey k in x.Keys)
            {
                TValue v = x[k];
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(v, null))
                    return object.ReferenceEquals(y[k], null);


                if (!v.Equals(y[k]))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }    

        public override int GetHashCode(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;

            int hash = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in obj)
            {
                int key = pair.Key.GetHashCode(); // key cannot be null
                int value = pair.Value != null ? pair.Value.GetHashCode() : 0;
                hash ^= ShiftAndWrap(key, 2) ^ value;
            }

            return hash;
        }

        private static int ShiftAndWrap(int value, int positions)
        {
            positions = positions & 0x1F;


            // Save the existing bit pattern, but interpret it as an unsigned integer. 
            uint number = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0);
            // Preserve the bits to be discarded. 
            uint wrapped = number >> (32 - positions);
            // Shift and wrap the discarded bits. 
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((number << positions) | wrapped), 0);
        }
    }
}
```